# Xaxis text overlapping - Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I plot a bar graph using **matplotlib** and everything works fine. When the **"text label"** on X-axis is too lengthy for each data point, then the text overlaps like shown in the figure. I also tried to rotate the alignment to **45** and **90** degrees, but the text goes beyond the frame.

[image]

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Y = [55,46,46,36,27,9]
point_labels =[50,38,25,6,6,6]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1)
ax2 = axes
n=7
ind=np.arange(n)
width=0.1
axis_font = {'fontname':'Arial', 'size':'11'}
Color = ['0.1','0.2','0.3','0.4','0.5','0.6']

bar = ax2.bar(X,Y,align="center",width=0.5,color=Color)
bar[0].set_color('r')

plt.xticks(ind+width/2, ('','Insufficient skills','Complex hardware and software','High initial investments','Complexity in collection and storing data','Insufficient hardware power for computing','Data collaboration'),horizontalalignment='center')

plt.ylabel('in precentage (%)')

text(4.6,52, '100% = 11 responses', style='italic',bbox={'facecolor':'red', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':10})

axes.yaxis.grid()
axes.set_ylim([0,60])

plt.show()
```

Can anyone suggest an idea to fix this?

Comment: can't you add a legend in place of the axis label?

Comment: @giosans  That would be my last approach if I don't find a solution.. But I believe there should be definitely a work around for this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can come up with is set the rotation as vertical changing the figure extension and run a `plt.tight_layout()`.
Those would be the last 3 lines of your code:

```
mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mngr.window.setGeometry(50,50,960, 640)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Alternatively, you should use multi lines with `\n`.
See http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiline.html
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Below solution worked for me

[How to prevent overlapping x-axis labels in sns.countplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528921/how-to-prevent-overlapping-x-axis-labels-in-sns-countplot)

```
plt.xticks(
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large'  
)
```