# How to prevent overlapping x-axis labels in sns.countplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, countplot

For the plot

```
sns.countplot(x="HostRamSize",data=df)
```

I got the following graph with x-axis label mixing together, how do I avoid this? Should I change the size of the graph to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-violin-plot) helps?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the figure size for a seaborn plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-plot)

Comment: This question is for axes-level functions (those with the `ax=` parameter), not figure-level functions. See [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions). See [How to rotate xticklabels in a seaborn catplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63909351/7758804) for figure-level plots.

Answer (score 105):

Having a Series `ds` like this

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(136)

l = "1234567890123"
categories = [ l[i:i+5]+" - "+l[i+1:i+6] for i in range(6)]
x = np.random.choice(categories, size=1000, 
            p=np.diff(np.array([0,0.7,2.8,6.5,8.5,9.3,10])/10.))
ds = pd.Series({"Column" : x})
```

there are several options to make the axis labels more readable.

#### Change figure size

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4)) # this creates a figure 8 inch wide, 4 inch high
sns.countplot(x="Column", data=ds)
plt.show()
```

#### Rotate the ticklabels

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="Column", data=ds)

ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Decrease Fontsize

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="Column", data=ds)

ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=7)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Of course any combination of those would work equally well.

#### Setting rcParams

The figure size and the xlabel fontsize can be set globally using [rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 4)
plt.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"] = 7
```

This might be useful to put on top of a juypter notebook such that those settings apply for any figure generated within. Unfortunately rotating the xticklabels is not possible using rcParams.

I guess it's worth noting that the same strategies would naturally also apply for seaborn barplot, matplotlib bar plot or pandas.bar.

Answer (score 15):

You can rotate the `x_labels` and increase their font size using the `xticks` methods of `pandas.pyplot`.

**For Example:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
chart = sns.countplot(x="HostRamSize",data=df)

plt.xticks(
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large'  
)
```

For more such modifications you can refer this link:
[Drawing from Data](https://www.drawingfromdata.com/how-to-rotate-axis-labels-in-seaborn-and-matplotlib)

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to make sure xticks labels are not squeezed together, you can set a proper fig size and try `fig.autofmt_xdate()`.

This function will automatically align and rotate the labels.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether it is an option for you but maybe turning the graphic could be a solution (instead of plotting on `x=`, do it on `y=`), such that:

```
sns.countplot(y="HostRamSize",data=df)
```

[image]