# To make bar plot in seaborn widely spread on y axis

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I want bars to widely spread in the graph so that graph is clearly visible.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnRG8.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnRG8.png

```
g=sns.barplot(y="Survived", x="Age", data=t,linewidth=10)
```

Comment: What is the problem? (It should be clear that when plotting `n` bars on an `x` inch wide figure, each bar will be `~x/n` wide) How would you like the graph to look like instead?

Comment: I want graph to be widely spread as the value of age is not visible in the graph it is overlapping

Comment: So you want to make the graph itself wider?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the sns countplot larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528921/how-to-make-the-sns-countplot-larger)

Comment: yes I want a clearer and wider graph

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-plot

Comment: Ok, I got my bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the figure size for a seaborn plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set figure size ([figsize](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html)) to make graph wider:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 3)

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
sns_plot = sns.boxplot(x=data)
```

[image]