# In Seaborn How to prevent overlapping axis in bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[To see the wrong Bar plot click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbSnB.png)

I want to plot a bar graph with x_axis is price and y_axis is inter-price time.But the price is a large amount of data, so in this plot, there`s too much bars and labels, so they`re  overlapping with each other and cannot read.I hope to decrease the labels but keep the bars.
How can I solve this problem?
the data is like:

0.05$ 1000

0.06$ 1200

0.04$ 1040

and the code is

```
# plot bar graph
plt.subplot(222)
ax2 = plt.gca()  # get axis
plt.xlabel('Price / $')# set label
plt.ylabel('Interval / Second')
ax2.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((0,1)) # set number
```

and use Seaborn to plot
`sns.barplot(df_sort['Price'],df_sort['Interval'],errwidth=1.0,palette="Blues_d",edgecolor='white')#plot`

Comment: **How** would you like the plot to look like instead? Note that if you plot 100 bars and each has a label, labels will of course overlap. Would you like to plot less bars, or leave out every second label or make the figure one meter wide?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent overlapping x-axis labels in sns.countplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528921/how-to-prevent-overlapping-x-axis-labels-in-sns-countplot)

Comment: @I want to have less bars.Such as just 5 or 6.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest You said quit right! The reason of overlapping is I have too much bars.And I don`t know how to only decrease the labels but remain the bars.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you very much for your help! I have solve this problem by decrease the label!!!!>_<