# How to rotate xticklabels in a seaborn catplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid, catplot

I'm not able to rotate my xlabels in Seaborn/Matplotlib. I have tried many different solutions but not able to fix it. I have seen many related questions here on stackoverflow, but they have not worked for me.

My current plot looks like this, but I want the xlabels to rotate 90.

[image]

```py
@staticmethod
def plotPrestasjon(plot):
    sns.set(style="darkgrid")
    ax = sns.catplot(x="COURSE", y="FINISH", hue="COURSE",
                     col="BIB#", data=plot, s=9, palette="Set2")
    ax.set(xlabel='COURSES', ylabel='FINISH (sec)')
    plt.show()
```

I have tried:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

But that fails to generate the plot. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- The correct way to set the xticklabels for [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html), according to the documentation, is with the `.set_xticklabels` method (.e.g. `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)`).
- Using a loop to iterate through the `Axes`, should be used if changes need to be made on a plot by plot basis, within the `FacetGrid`.
- [Building structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)
- [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)
- `g`, or in the case of the OP, `ax` is a `seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid`

  - When iterating through `ax.axes.flat`, `axes` is a `<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>`, which has a wide array of class methods, including `.get_xticklabels()`.
- In cases with many columns, and `col_wrap=` is used, `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)` may result in removing all the xticklabels.

  - Instead, `labels=` must be specified, `g.set_xticklabels(g.axes.flat[-1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)`, where `g.axes.flat[-1]` should be the last facet axes with xticklabels.
  - Alternatively, use `g.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30)`
- **Tested in `python 3.12`, `matplotlib 3.8.1`, `seaborn 0.13.0`**

#### One Row & Multiple Columns

```py
import seaborn as sns

# load data
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# plot catplot
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)

# set rotation
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

[image]

#### Multiple Rows & Columns

```py
# plot catplot
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="diet", col="kind", col_wrap=2, data=exercise)

# set rotation using one of the following options
# g.set_xticklabels(labels=g.axes.flat[-1].get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
g.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30)
```

[image]

---

- Using `g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)` results in an `AttributeError`.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-442-d1d39d8cc4f0> in <module>
      1 g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)
----> 2 g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)

AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'get_xticklabels'
```

Comment: Yes that is indeed the more appropriate solution. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 3):

Try iterating through the axes that belong to the `FacetGrid`:

```
for axes in ax.axes.flat:
    axes.set_xticklabels(axes.get_xticklabels(), 
                         rotation=90, 
                         horizontalalignment='right')
```

- A `FacetGrid` is composed of a collection of `Axes`, and some of the methods that look so intuitive for the whole "plot", are actually meant to be used on each individual `Axes`. Search for `Axes` in the [documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html). You'll see they often iterate through them when they need to change a feature that pertains to each individual subplot (as opposed to the whole plot's legend, for example).